# Bonjour/Zeroconf in .NET on Win7 x64

Tags: c#, 64-bit, bonjour, zeroconf

did anyone ever try to publish a netservice via Bonjour on a x64 system? I tried several  libraries like [Mono.Zeroconf](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf), [Deusty](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/03/bonjour-for-net.html) (there's some x64-discussion in the comments) and [Zeroconf.Codeplex](http://zeroconf.codeplex.com/). They're working perfectly as long as I build my application for platform target x86.
All I want to do is to publish my service into a LAN on any Win7 machine (x86/x64).

Every hint is highly appreciated!

Best Regards,
Waescher

Comment: Okay, I ripped out the whole bonjour/zeroconf some days ago and went back to the good old udp broadcast. Here's a pretty good sample: http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/03/27/locating-network-services-on-the-iphoneipad-with-monotouch/

Comment: I tried a lot of things to publish Zeroconf service in .NET on Win7 x64 and finally succeeded with [Apple Bonjour SDK for Windows](http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/download/) - i think you need to be registered as an Apple developer.

Comment: did you use http://craz.net/programs/ZeroconfNetServices/ ?