# Is there a way to detect bonjour/mdns/zeroconf/any services in local network in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8, zeroconf, mdns

In WPF application I could add reference to `Bonjour 1.0` therefore I was able to detect bonjour services in local network. In Windows Phone application I see no references to Bonjour avaiable. How to deal with that?

My problem is that I would like to create/broadcast a service on a PC which can be detected(ip and port) by the Windows Phone cellphone. Both(PC and Cell) are in the same local network(one router).

Comment: Did you seen [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890280/bonjour-zeroconf-in-net-on-win7-x64)?

Comment: This is a topic about receiving multicast messages on windows phone [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286407(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: @MrKlin I looked through that but if I understand that topic right you have to first know the ip(you human:P have insert it by hand). There is nothing said about searching the service's ip.

Comment: @Yoda, This is because these kind of services work in multicast, where each server publish itself to everyone else. All you have to do is receive the message and parse according to spec.

Comment: There's a Zeroconf implementation for WP8 [here](https://github.com/onovotny/Zeroconf). Only resolution, no service announcement. Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I used Apple's Bonjour .NET SDK.